# Flashed bootloader, now adb/fastboot no longer see the device

Tags: android, adb, bootloader, fastboot

I was restoring a nexus s to a factory image as I've done before on other nexus s phones.  After flashing the bootloader, I can no longer connect to the phone with ADB.  "Enable USB debugging" is checked in developer options, but USB debugging never starts when I plug the phone in.  This phone previously had a custom version of jelly bean on it and I was flashing it to ICS.  Anyone have any tips for how I can get adb working again on this phone?

Here is the shell output where things went wrong.  After flashing the bootloader, fastboot could no longer connect to flash the radio.  The script used to flash the phone is at the end of the output.

```
zzz:$ pwd
/Users/zzz/Downloads/soju-imm76d
zzz:$ ls
bootloader-crespo-i9020xxkl1.img    flash-all.sh                flash-base.sh               image-soju-imm76d.zip           radio-crespo-i9020xxki1.img
zzz:$ flash-all.sh
sending 'bootloader' (1536 KB)...
OKAY [  0.282s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  0.369s]
finished. total time: 0.651s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.001s]
finished. total time: 0.001s
< waiting for device >
^C
zzz:$ more flash-all.sh
#!/bin/sh

# Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-crespo-i9020xxkl1.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
sleep 5
fastboot flash radio radio-crespo-i9020xxki1.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
sleep 5
fastboot -w update image-soju-imm76d.zip
zzz:$ fastboot devices
zzz:$ fastboot device
< waiting for device >
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to connect your phone with QSTP tool and use eMMC softwaredownloader for flashing the phone

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Linux? You must run fastboot as root. Try `sudo fastboot`.

Same for other similar commands, so you may want to consider going `sudo -i` and go on from there.

Answer (score -1):

I am having somewhat the same issue with my XT890, think flashing the bootloader has `hard-bricked` the device. Meaning Although you can switch the device on, as there is no valid `bootloader` you can't connect to the device or recover the device.